# Dynamic PopupMenu with custom xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Hi is it possible to have a dynamic `PopupMenu` with a custom xml layout file? Right now I am using it like this:

```
 popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, subView);
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(DEVICE_GROUP, DEVICE_LOCATION_1, Menu.NONE, "Warehouse B");
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(DEVICE_GROUP, DEVICE_LOCATION_2, Menu.NONE, "Stockroom Store 1");
        popupMenu.getMenu().add(DEVICE_GROUP, DEVICE_LOCATION_3, Menu.NONE, "Stockroom Outlet");
```

These are just example data, the menu items are going to be added dynamically later on.
For example I would like it to have a different width and size for the `PopupMenu` and some other possibilities too.

Could anyone help me? thx

Comment: Have you tried  android.app.DialogFragment ?

Comment: @Stallion thx for the suggestion, but it seems a bit overkill, since I want to resize the width and height for now only.

Comment: You may try PopupWindow where you can inflate your custom view as well.